# MEF import does not work with a Shell that has more than one active screen

Tags: wpf, shell, screen, mef, caliburn.micro

Hi I user WPF/Calibur Micro/MEF. I I try have more active screen in shell. First I define screens - User controls.

1. Screen - View model

> ```
> public interface IProjectsViewModel
> {
>
> }
> [Export(typeof(IProjectsViewModel))]
> public class ProjectsViewModel:Screen,
>     IProjectsViewModel
> {
>
> }
> ```

2.Screen -View Model

> ```
> public interface IProjectInfoViewModel
> {
>
> }
>
> [Export(typeof(IProjectInfoViewModel))]
> public class ProjectInfoViewModel :Screen, 
>     IProjectInfoViewModel
> {
>     [Import]
>     internal IMessageBox MsgBox { get; set; }
>
>     public void BtnClick()
>     {
>         MsgBox.ShowInfo("Btn click",string.Empty);
>     }
> }
> ```

I second screen I have only one button if user click on the button it showed message box.

No most important part shell. Shell is WPF window.

View:

```
<Window x:Class="CaliburnSkelet.Views.ShellView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
        xmlns:Views="clr-namespace:CaliburnSkelet.Views" 
        xmlns:cal="clr-namespace:Caliburn.Micro;assembly=Caliburn.Micro" 
        Title="ShellView" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <!--<ContentControl x:Name="Projects" Grid.Column="0"/>
        <ContentControl x:Name="ProjectInfo" Grid.Column="1"/>-->
        <Views:ProjectsView  cal:View.Model="{Binding Projects}" 
                             Grid.Column="0"/>
        <Views:ProjectInfoView cal:View.Model="{Binding ProjectInfo}"
                               Grid.Column="1"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

ShellViewModel:

> ```
> public interface IShellViewModel :IScreen
> {
>     ProjectInfoViewModel ProjectInfo { get; set; }
>     ProjectsViewModel Project { get; set; }
> }
>
> [Export(typeof(IShellViewModel))]
> public class ShellViewModel:Conductor<IScreen>.Collection.AllActive,
>     IShellViewModel, IPartImportsSatisfiedNotification
>
> {
>     [Import]
>     public ProjectInfoViewModel ProjectInfo { get; set; }
>
>     [Import]
>     public ProjectsViewModel Project { get; set; }
>
>     public void OnImportsSatisfied()
>     {
>     }
> }
> ```

If I try compile this code I get error:

> Could not locate any instances of contract
>   CaliburnSkelet.ViewModels.IShellViewModel.

StackTrace:

```
  at CaliburnSkelet.BootStraper.MefBootStrapper.GetInstance(Type serviceType, String key) in E:\C# PROJECTS\CaliburnSkelet\CaliburnSkelet\BootStraper\MefBootStrapper.cs:line 69
   at Caliburn.Micro.Bootstrapper.DisplayRootViewFor(Type viewModelType)
   at Caliburn.Micro.Bootstrapper`1.OnStartup(Object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Application.OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Application.<.ctor>b__1(Object unused)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
```

I tried make a test and change properties shell view model class.

```
[Export(typeof(IShellViewModel))]
public class ShellViewModel:Conductor<IScreen>.Collection.AllActive,
    IShellViewModel, IPartImportsSatisfiedNotification

{
    //[Import]
    public ProjectInfoViewModel ProjectInfo { get; set; }

    //[Import]
    public ProjectsViewModel Project { get; set; }

    public void OnImportsSatisfied()
    {
        ProjectInfo=new ProjectInfoViewModel();
        Project=new ProjectsViewModel();
    }
}
```

I don’t import view models classes to shell view model with MEF but I create new instances in method OnImportsSatisfied.

Application run but if I click on button  variable MsgBox is null.

Code from ProjectInfoViewModel class:

```
        [Import]
        internal IMessageBox MsgBox { get; set; }

        public void BtnClick()
        {
//MsgBox is null
            MsgBox.ShowInfo("Btn click",string.Empty);
        }
```

Where can be problem?

> here? Conductor.Collection.AllActive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your `ShellViewModel` type, the `ProjectInfo` and `Project` properties should be of type `IProjectInfoViewModel` and `IProjectsViewModel`, as these are the types you have exported, and you should be working against those interfaces.

Comment: Thank you very much, stupid problem...I export view model classes as interfaces...you are right